# Saving Multiple Local/Offline Files to Target Folder with OS Module

Tags: python

I am trying to move all files that are in Just `source_path` to the `target_path`.

Here is the code:

```
import os

target_path = 'C:/Users/Justi/source/repos/GUI Developmentv3/Test 02' + '\\'
source_path ='C:/Users/Justi/source/repos/GUI Developmentv3/' + '\\' 

for path, dir, files in os.walk(source_path):
    if files:
        for file in files:
            if not os.path.isfile(target_path + file):
                os.rename(path + '\\' + file, target_path + file)
```

However, this also moves other files that are in the sub-directory folders of the source folder into the target folder.

May I check how I could change the code to only move files at the exact directory of `source_path` without affecting files in `source_path`'s sub-dictionary? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the usage of [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), because it walks the whole tree. See the docs:

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up.

You are only interested in the contents of a particular folder, so [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) is more suitable:

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.

The following code will iterate over the files in the `source` dir, and move only the files into the `target` dir.

```
import os
import shutil

source = "source"
target = "target"

for f in os.listdir(source):
    print(f"Found {f}")
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, f)):
        print(f"{f} is a file, will move it to target folder")
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), os.path.join(target, f))
```